Tobler's function in QGIS
I would like to estimate the least cost path between a source point to a group of other points. I would consider the cost as travel time by using Tobler's function in QGIS (I am new with it).
What are the process steps to get a friction surface on which estimate the least cost path?
As data, I have the DTM of the area, the source point and the arrival points.
